# Angular 7 flex layout make table full fill parent but not stretch parent

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

Hi I am having an issue with the example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vejx7v). Basically I want to restrict the table in one page and fill the rest of the height after the header. If the table's height is more than that, I would like it to hide. But from the example, it seems like the table stretch its parent. What can I do to limit the table's height? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `height` of div and use `overflow` property:

```
<div fxLayout='column' fxFill style=' border: red 10px solid'>
  <div>
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div style='border: 1px solid black; overflow: auto; height:100px' fxFill>
    <table fxFlex='100%'>
      <!-- The code omitted for the brevity -->
      <tr><td>a</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:

Another way without fixed height:

```
<div style="height: 100vh;">
<div fxLayout='column' fxFill style=' border: red 10px solid; display: flex; 
    flex-direction:column; position:absolute;top: 0; 
    bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;'>
  <div style="flex-shrink: 0;">
    <h1>Header 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div style='border: 10px solid orange; overflow-y: auto;' fxFill>
    <table fxFlex='100%'>
      <!-- The code omitted for the brevity -->
      <tr><td>a</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td></tr>
      <tr><td>a</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi StepUp, thank you for your suggestion. However since I m note sure how high the Header section is, it will be very hard to determine the value for height. Setting a value to height seems quite rigid.